# Any experience about tile construct in OpenMP?

Tags: openmp

Even though there are many questions here regarding loop tiling, there are no questions regarding **tile OpenMP construct**, and I would like to ask if there are conditions that have to be met in order to achieve better performance via this construct.

I used this construct in a loop that works correctly (meaning that the speedup is increased with the number of threads and reaches an upper limit as it is predicted by Amdahl's law) using the directive

```
#pragma omp for firstprivate (......) schedule(.....) nowait
```

However, when I substitute this line with the line

```
#pragma omp tile sizes (x,x) private (.......)
```

(x=2,3,4) the speedup remains the same for a thread number from 1 to (about) 8 or 10 and then it is continually decreases (the parallel execution time increases). The remaining code is exactly the same. Any idea that explains this behaviour? Thanks a lot and happy holidays to everyone !!

Comment: `tile` seems to be an OpenMP 5.1 feature therefore you wont find many questions about it and compiler support might also not be ideal yet.

Comment: By substitute you mean you add the `tile` pragma? The `tile` pragma itself doesn't replace the `#pragma omp for`. It is still needed s.t. different threads process different parts of the tiled loop nest. See [OpenMP 5.1 Samples](https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/openmp-examples-5.1.pdf) page 273.

Comment: Note that [GCC (14) does not support it yet](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/openmp) and [Clang support it only since Clang 13.0.0](https://releases.llvm.org/13.0.0/tools/clang/docs/OpenMPSupport.html) (released 2 years ago).

Comment: Small tiles can certainly be unrolled in Clang (or ICC which is now based on Clang). When the number of instruction becomes significant, unrolling is not a good idea and the compiler do not unroll it. This can prevent some optimization. Regarding your exact code, cache effects may also have an impact.

Comment: @Jérôme Richard: I know that if a #pragma directive is not supported by gcc it is silently ignored without any warning. It is possible, via e.g. some command line argument to get informed about this?

Comment: @AthanasiosMargaris You can use `-Wall` for GCC while it is not as good as what Clang does by default and more general (note that ignoring such a pragma is perfectly valid in OpenMP). By the way, I found out meanwhile that the clause `sizes(xxx,xxx)` is actually only supported since Clang 17.0 and not before.